# Design matrix with intersec 0 or 1

Tags: r, regression, experiment-design, matrix, lm

I am constructing a model matrix for a repeated meassurments experiment with three individuals per group and three treatments per individual.

```
Gps <- factor(c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3)) # Groups
Tts <- factor(c("A","B","C","B","A","C","C","B","A")) # Treatments
```

This model matrix makes sense to me, since it estimates the variance within each individual, using the per individual mean of treatment A as the intercept.

```
model.matrix(~0+Gps+Tts)
```

However, I often see a matrix like this:

```
model.matrix(~Gps+Tts)
```

What is the difference between the two model matrices?

Answer (score 0):

The `model.matrix` with `0` in the formula does not contain a column for an `intercept`, which corresponds to the reference level in the design. So in that case you are not interested in estimating the basic value in the reference level.

Comment: In the model matrix with 0, the reference level would be mean of treatment A at each individual.
In the model matrix with 1, the reference level would be mean of treatment A using all individuals.
Is this correct?

Comment: In the model matrix with 1, the reference level would be mean of treatment A using all individuals treated with A.

Comment: wouldn't that inflate the variance and therefore not be the right model for repeated measurements?

Comment: reference level would be treatment A and group 1